# Extractign markups and comments from an A360 file

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

i suppose there most be a way to do this, but so far all the info i can find focus on viewing the model and accessing information that already is IN in the model/file.

How do i access the info that users create inside the A360 platform, like comments and markups.

any info that can point me out in the right direction will be much appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Hi, does those information you mentioned is created by Revit or Naviswroks  or older A360 viewer? If yes, this might not available current;y as I know, Forge Model Derivative API will ignore those data during the translation procedure. But you can extract those information to database or file via the Revit API or Navisworks API, and load it in your Fore Viewer app to show it in your desired way.

Comment: If those information you mentioned is created by the current version of the A360 viewer, it might be possible to be accessed via the `NOP_Viewer`, the Forge Viewer instance of the A360, in the browser dev console. But there is still  no way to customize A360 platform currently as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately markups and comments created in A360 are not exposed through a public API at this time, sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Well that's really bad, half of our projects only use A360 for the revisions with clients and consultants. But thanks for the answers guys!